# How do you print a grid of asterisks using multidimensional arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to programming and I have an exercise that's killing me. How can you print a grid (5-by-6) which consists of asterisks alone? [Later on, these asterisks will have to be replaced by letters which are read in with StdIn.readInt() and a switch statement, but for now I at least need to understand how to print the grid]. I would appreciate any help so much!

More specifically, the grid should look like this:

```
//THIS ISN'T THE CODE; JUST AN ILLUSTRATION OF WHAT SHOULD BE PRINTED

  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 * * * * * *
1 * * * * * *
2 * * * * * *
3 * * * * * *
4 * * * * * *

//I AM SUPPOSED TO START WITH SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

public class Grid {
 static int X = 6;
 static int Y = 7;
public static void main(String[]args) {
    int [][] grid = new int [X][Y];
```

Comment: Look at `System.out.print()` and note that you can print "\n" to get a line break.

Comment: Are you familiar with for loop?

Comment: Do you need numbers above and aside?

Comment: @Joakim I have to use arrays, so I cant Just print it, and the grid will change with time.

Comment: @MS90   Yes, I need the numbers there

Comment: Yes, use the print method with your array and for - loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This could have been done in many ways, but this is my way of doing it:**

When you want to print a grid, you have to use 2 nested `for` loops.
Let's see what happens when you use 2 nested `for` loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

   for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){

   }
}
```

We start with the first loop:

for `i = 0`, we will enter the second loop and iterate from 0 to 6.

for `i = 1`, we will enter the second loop and iterate from 0 to 6.

...

for `i = 5`, we will enter the second loop and iterate from 0 to 6.

What you should notice is that `j` will iterate and take values from 0 to 6 with each value of `i`.

Going back to your question, and comparing it by what i just showed, you should notice that for each **line**, you are printing **7 values** (of a column).

Let's assume `i` is the number of lines, and `j` is the index of each value in that line (column).

```
public static void printGrid() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }
```

This code prints on each **line** (`i`), 7 asterixes (`j`).
And each time i is incrementing, we are going back to the next line `System.out.println()`. That's why we put it inside the `for` loop with `i`.

In your situation, we have to tweak this code a little bit to be able to print the numbers on the sides, and that space at the top left corner.

The explanation is in the comments in my code.

```
public class Question_55386466{

        static int X = 6;
        static int Y = 7;

        public static void printGrid() {
            System.out.print("  ");         // Printing the space on the top left corner
            for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
                if (i > 0) {                // Printing the numbers column on the left, taking i>0 to start from the second line (i == 1)
                    System.out.println();   // Going to the next line after printing the whole line
                    System.out.print(i - 1);//Printing the numbers of the column. Taking i-1 because we start the count for i == 1 not 0
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++) {
                    if (i == 0)
                        System.out.print(j + "  ");//Print the first line numbers.
                    else
                        System.out.print(" * "); //if the line isn't the first line(i == 0), print the asterixes.

                }

            }
        }
```

You can always edit the values of `X` and `Y` and get the desired result.

And later you can give this method your array as a parameter and print each element instead of the asterixes.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm free to do it or not. And if you read what he commented above, he said that he needs the numbers there. So it looks like it's not me that misunderstood what should be printed.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I understand it much better and it works perfectly. Appreciate it!